# Delete value from Dropdown list

Tags: php

I'm trying to Code a function that allow me to delete a selected value from a Dropdown list.

```
<?php
require_once("db.inc.php");
?>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
 <?php





$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT anr, name FROM artikel");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($anr, $name);


echo "<select name='selected_name'><br />";

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

echo '<option value='.$anr.'>'.$anr.' | '.$name.'</option>';


if(isset($_POST['loeschen'])){

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM artikel WHERE anr=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $anr);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $mysqli->close();

    }

}   


  ?>
  <input type="submit" value="Datensatz löschen" name="loeschen">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My Problem is that the values are going to be deleted even i don't press the submit button. Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: You need to delete the row from the database before you select the rows you want to display. Also note that your code will delete all options from the database; you are not checking / using the value of `$_POST['selected_name']`

Comment: Do you want delete selected value without submitting?

Comment: No, i want to delete only after submitting

Comment: is this question still open here? unsolved? you've a few answers given but none accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Post value instead of $anr.

```
<?php
require_once("db.inc.php");
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['selected_name'])){

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM artikel WHERE anr=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['selected_name']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $mysqli->close();

    }

}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
 <?php

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT anr, name FROM artikel");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($anr, $name);
echo "<select name='selected_name'><br />";
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
echo '<option value='.$anr.'>'.$anr.' | '.$name.'</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
  ?>
  <input type="submit" value="Datensatz löschen" name="loeschen">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

only mistake is instead of this `$stmt->bind_param('i', $anr)` use below

```
   $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['selected_name']));
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: After pressing the submit button i receive the following advise:

Comment: Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\ysql7\test.php on line 24

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ysql7\test.php on line 25

Comment: that selected value integer or string.

Comment: we binding integer. ``$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['selected_name']));``

Comment: Ok, but in the Dropdown List i have to values, one integer and one string. Is this the Problem? In the Code i've choose to delete the value using the integer value.

Comment: Yes. It may be the problem. Better you can use s instead of i.

Comment: NOTE;: After refreshing the Website the value is deleted despite the warning

Comment: I've found the Problem. It was the "mysqli->Close" code.